# VSCode run python tests on conda environment

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have a conda environment `tf` which includes tensorflow. I wrote tests using [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) which works correctly from shell on `tf` environment. However VSCode says that no tests were discovered. When I remove the `import tensorflow` line VSCode properly discovers tests.

How can I make VSCode to handle tests with dependencies on `tf` environment?

Comment: May I ask whether you ever found a solution to this?